# Filtering out high frequency from my input graph

Tags: low-pass, active-filter

I have an input whose waveform looks something like this:[image]

It repeats over and over again until the source if turned off.[image]

It is composed of waves of 2 frequencies (16kHz and 1kHz). The final source wave is the `AND` of the two waves, which is shown in the 2 pictures above. You could say the 16kHz wave is the carrier wave and the 1kHz wave is the message wave. I need to filter out the 16kHz wave and keep only the 1Khz wave. So the final waveform is just a square wave of 1kHz frequency. I tried using envelope detector, but my case doesnt satisfy the conditions (fc >> 1/RC >> fm). When I use normal low pass filter, I dont get a good waveform because the capacitor discharges too quick and hence the ripples are sharper. Also the attenuation is very high, I need the output waveform to be at the same level as the input. If I use an active filter for this, the ripples get even sharper. I tried changing the RC values so that the capacitor doesnt discharge as quick but then the attenuation is increased. How do I get a clean output waveform?
This is my current output.
[image]

Comment: You can't use a filter directly be ause the frequencies of the waveforms are partially overlapping due to the harmonics on the square waves. What property of the lower frequency square wave is of interest? Amplitude, phase or frequency? If this is something like a clock waveform I would filter it down to a sin wave, then clamp it back to square with a logic gate.

Comment: I am definitely interested in the frequency of the lower freq wave. I need to send this to my Arduino interrupt pin and calculate the frequency. Also, since I am sending it to my arduino pin, I must ensure the amplitude of the wave is less than 5V. I just used an AND gate here for the sake of generating the source wave, and hence it is shown as 1V amplitude but in reality, I am getting this input wave from another source with 12V amplitude (both waves). I plan on using a simple resistive divider after getting my filtered wave to reduce it to 5V.

Comment: The frequency of the low freq wave will vary from 50Hz to 1kHz from the actual source. I need to find out the frequency using the arduino pin. In reality, I do not know the frequency of the lower wave, but the above circuit for just for the readers to understand the problem here

Comment: I like the software solution suggested below if you don't know the lower frequency in advance, but what I suggested will also work if you want a hardware solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in software. The modulated signal can trigger an interrupt where you (re-)start a one shot timer. Set the timeout period to 70 µs. The timeout will happen only if the 16 kHz pulses do not come in time. This is the desired trigger for the frequency calculation of the modulated signal.

Such a retriggerable monoflop in discrete components could look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fT1w7N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The timeout of the monoflop is dominated by C1 and R5. The falling edge at the output is not perfect sharp, but is good enough for an interrupt input.

A solution with CMOS Schmitt Trigger CD4093 or a TTL solution with 74123 is an alternative.